# TranslationWorker-RecoverableInternalFailure: Extractor - Adapter Process Timeout Error -777

Tags: autodesk, forge

We're having an issue with a specific Inventor Pack-and-Go Zip File Where The Translation Process Always Results in: TranslationWorker-RecoverableInternalFailure: Extractor - Adapter Process Timeout Error -777.

```
{
    "Type": "manifest",
    "HasThumbnail": false,
    "Status": "failed",
    "Progress": "complete",
    "Region": "US",
    "URN": "",
    "Version": "1.0",
    "Derivatives": {
        "0": {
            "name": "LMV Bubble",
            "hasThumbnail": "false",
            "status": "failed",
            "progress": "complete",
            "messages": {
                "0": {
                    "type": "error",
                    "message": "Extractor - Adapter Process Timeout Error -777",
                    "code": "TranslationWorker-RecoverableInternalFailure"
                }
            },
            "outputType": "svf"
        }
    }
}
```

We've ensured that our token is still active and even added additional refresh steps.  However, we're not sure what to do next to resolve.